# Open button not present in IE 11 when exporting data to csv

Tags: angular

I am using angular2-csv [https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv] in my Angular 4 app to export data to csv.

Below is the data that does the export

```
export() {

    let exportResults: any[] = [];

    var options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      showLabels: true
    };
    this.myService.export(input).subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        exportResults = JSON.parse(response.text());
        new Angular2Csv(exportResults, 'Exported Data', options);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }
```

This code exports the data to csv as expected, however in IE11, it does not show the 'Open' button. It does have 'Save', 'SaveAs' and 'Cancel' options though.

[image: Without open button]

I do realize that this pop out is shown by IE so we don't have much control over it. However, I have seen 'Open' button displayed in IE11 when downloading files. So wanted to check if there is something that we can do to get the Open button.

[image: With open button]

Both the screenshots above are from the same user machine downloading csv from 2 different applications. One shows an Open button and the other one (for which I have pasted the code above) does not.

Answer (score 1):

IE won't show an 'Open' button when user do not have any application associated with downloaded file type, or if associated application for given file type is set to IE. There's nothing to do that from developer's point of view. It depends on user's configuration only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Users do have an application associated with csv, as when they download csv from another site they are able to see the Open button.

Comment: In dark times of IE8, things like that was possible: https://www.nwebsec.com/HttpHeaders/SecurityHeaders/XDownloadOptions I don't know if there is something similar for IE11.

Comment: Yes, couldn't find anything specific to IE11 that could help.